# BPEL- importing WSDL with same namespace - uninitializedPartnerRole: null

Tags: wsdl, wso2, soa, bpel

I am designing a BPEL process using 2 partner WSDL files. The problem is that the two WSDLs are having the same namespace

I tried to fix the error using the steps (2nd approach) mentioned in the the URL (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21231969) which is nothing but WSDL chaining. This removed my compilation error.

But, While testing the BPEL process, I am getting the following run time exception 
uninitializedPartnerRole: null)].

Can anybody please suggest a solution. I am using WSO2 3.2.1 BPS server and BPEL 2.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of struggle, I figured out the solution for the solution,
Here is what I did to fix the issue,
Step 1) I added the attribute initializePartnerRole with a value "yes"
 for the partner link which was causing this issue.

Step 2) In the deploy.xml, I added the partner link as an outbound interface.
    
      
    
I deployed the BPEL process in the WSO2 server and it resolved the issue.

However, I am trying to understand, the signifacence of initializePartnerRole="yes" attribute in the partner link attribute. Any input would be helpful? Thanks